# AddWithValue() in PostgreSQL from .Net

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, npgsql

I have been reading about this topic but haven´t found any particular documentation related to Npgsql, so I thought it would be a good idea to post a question in the great Stack Overflow :-).

We know that using parameters in queries and functions (or stored procedures) calls through command.Parameters.AddWithValue(...) or command.Parameters.Add(...) prevents SQL injection (as stated in the Parameters Section of the [official Npgsql documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html)).

However, I have found some relevant information about the type conversion that SQL Server needs to do when .Net does not infer the correct data type. There is a great article about this [here](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already).

So, when calling a function from C# through Npgsql and adding parameters with AddWithValue(), the conversion happens in every row or in the call? If there is a type mismatch between the data type of the parameter and the C# code, could still be affecting results and/or performance? It would be a good idea to use Add() explicitly specifying the data type instead of AddWithValue()?

I hope anyone can shed some light on this! Thank you in advanced!

Comment: A parameter is only passed once, not per row. `.AddWithValue()` should be avoided because you know (or ought to know) what type the DB engine is expecting, and you should ideally prevent .NET from inferring anything by simply telling it what the correct parameter type is. Basically `.AddWithValue()` is a convenience method that is never superior to an explicit `.Add()`. Best case everything works out and the types match up, worst case the wrong type is inferred and the DB engine either gives an error or (worse) silently converts the value again in a surprising way.

Comment: See https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/, while intended for SQL Server it's also relevant for Postgres

Comment: Nice article @Charlieface! However it also point to SQL Server and not PostgreSQL. Thanks for the link, very interesting and a perfect complement to the article I have linked.

Comment: As I said, it's also relevant for Postgres. The parameter is passed once, but on the server side there may be many things that might happen. It may have picked the correct type, it may have picked one that the server will convert to the column type. Either of these is not a problem. The problem starts when the server decides to convert the column's type to the parameter's type, then it will get a conversion for each row, and cannot use indexes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @JeroenMostert! Your comment is a great summary of the articles linked in this post. However, I´m not sure if that works the same way in Npgsql with PostgreSQL. As you said, parameters in a query are passed once, but in some cases SQL Server makes one conversion per row (the second article describes the varchar to nvarchar case as an example). Everything indicates that we should use Add() instead of AddWithValue(), what I am looking for is more information about the behavior of Npgsql and PostgreSQL with both of them.

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html#write-mappings):

There are three rules that determine the PostgreSQL type sent for a parameter:

1. If the parameter's NpgsqlDbType is set, it is used.
2. If the parameter's DataType is set, it is used.
3. If the parameter's DbType is set, it is used.

- If none of the above is set, the backend type will be inferred from the CLR - value type.

If you set dataType to AddWithValue it will work a little bit faster because not will be inferred from the CLR. Example:

```cs
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@length", NpgsqlDbType.Bigint, length);
```

But if you want to insert many records you can use one of fastests methods [from here](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html#binary-copy). It is `binary writer` for write and `binary reader` for read